# Assign Tier labels to accounts based on range in spending

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How would I assign Tiers in one column (Tier 1, Tier 2, and Tier 3) to accounts, based on spending data in another column? Specifically, with the following ranges:

- Tier 1: $500,000 - $2 million
- Tier 2: $200,000 to $500,000
- Tier 3: Up to $200,000

Comment: Please describe more clearly what data you have and what you want Excel to do.

Comment: I have the annual spending data for hundreds of company accounts and I need to add a column that assigns Tiers to them based on a range of spend (as mentioned above). At a glance I want to be able to see that an account is Tier 1 or so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if you have a spending total in, say, cell `Q17`, then just put

```
=IF(Q17<20000, "Tier 3", IF(Q17<500000, "Tier 2", IF(Q17<=2000000, "Tier 1", "Off the scale!")))
```

in whatever cell you want the tier number to appear in.